# How to take values from another column and pass to other if other is NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is an example of my Dataframe:

```
  HIP       Ident       
KOI-23      36130
KOI-321     27223
KOI-452     22329
  NaN       74773
  NaN       12831
```

What I'm trying to do is take the 'Ident' column values and copy them to 'HIP' column when they are NaN, so they would look like this:

```
  HIP         Ident       
KOI-23        36130
KOI-321       27223
KOI-452       22329
 74773        74773
 12831        12831
```

I've tried using np.where like this, but it didn't work.

```
df['HIP']=np.where(df['HIP'].isnull(), df['HIP'], df['ident'])
```

So, how can I achieve that?

Comment: try ``df.bfill(axis=1)``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use `.fillna`:

```
df['HIP'] = df['HIP'].fillna(df['Ident'])
df.head(10)
#output:
    HIP     Ident
0   KOI-23  36130
1   KOI-321 27223
2   KOI-452 22329
3   74773   74773
4   12831   12831
```

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is opposite change `isnull` to `notnull`

```
df['HIP'] = np.where(df['HIP'].notnull(), df['HIP'], df['Ident'])
```